# writing to fstream every millisecond vs bulk write

Tags: c++, fstream

I want to be able to record to file readings from several sensors which produce readings every millisecond. My question is whether I should be worried about writing about 100 `double` values divided among several different `fstream` files every millisecond. Would it be "safer" to just record the values in a buffer and then write them to file when recording stops?

Comment: I recommend throwing the values into a buffer.  Periodically (like every second or 500 ms), then bulk write to the files.  You should also flush the buffers when the recording stops.  I don't think that the hard drives can handle writing every ms.

Comment: I assume the periodic writing would be done in separate thread?

Comment: Depends on your platform.  Yes, you can have a thread or task that wakes up, writes the data, then goes back to sleep.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Doesn't `std::fstream` has its own buffer?

Comment: @AlexanderZhang: The `std::fstream` has a buffer, but the size is implementation specific.  By creating your own buffer, you can create it in multiples of 512 bytes, like 51200 bytes.  I don't think that `std::fstream` buffer is as large.